# FCKEditor breaking HTML forms

Tags: html, validation, forms, fckeditor

I'm in the process of reproducing some standalone HTML forms as pages in a CMS that uses FCKEditor by simply copying and pasting the relevant code into the editor.

But when I save and view the page, the HTML has been changed and the  tag has been moved up to just below the open  tag -- and not at the bottom of the form. This obviously renders all of the fields in the form, including the submit button, useless.

Is there a way to tell FCKEditor that I know what I'm doing and I don't need it to validate the HTML output?

Unfortunately this is a hosted CMS service (actually part of an email blast tool) so making changes to the configuration will mean I need to go through the company's support system, which is fine -- but they haven't been able to solve it for me yet, so I'm hoping to get the answers for them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a difficult thing because as far as I know, it's not necessarily the WYSIWYG editors that "fix" "broken" HTML, it's the browsers' HTML editing engines themselves, and it's often near impossible to talk them out of doing this.

You'd have to show your exact source to get detailed feedback, but check out whether [`protectedSource`](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Configuration_Options/ProtectedSource.Add) is something for you. It's supposed to protect code that is covered by the regular expression you specify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about FCKEditor, but you might want to consider switching to TinyMCE. TinyMCE allows you to both edit a list of allowed tags, and to turn off HTML validation off completely if you like.